# Using google spreadsheets with android

Tags: android, google-sheets

I have stored a bunch of village related health information on gooogle spreadsheets for an organization. It is currently split on the basis of a sheet for each village. I am creating an android application to access these fields and edit them. The other functionality that is needed is that I also need a row's worth of information to be stored on the phone and when there is a mobile connection, it will sync with the google spreadsheet. I have been trying to use http://code.google.com/p/google-spreadsheet-lib-android/. Does anyone know if this is the best option or how I should approach this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the official Google Spreadsheet API [here.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) Which does have some benefits because it's from straight from Google so you know what you're getting. I'm fairly new to Android so I used the GSS library in one of my early projects and I found it really easy to work with, the only problem is that it hasn't been updated since October 2011. That means that it's probably v1 or v2 of the Spreadsheet API and according to Google those versions will be shut down soon.

> Important: Versions 1 and 2 of the Google Spreadsheets API have been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012 and will be shut down on October 20, 2012. Migration to v3 should be simple, as it includes all the features of v1 and v2, thus you only need to stop specifying v1 or v2 with your requests. We recommend that you update your apps to send requests to v3 as soon as possible.

**Edit**:

I just checked the library and he quotes viewing the API version 3.0 documentation so it seems it's ok to use.

Comment: ok thank you. I actually started using the google spreadsheets api today. It seems like it should suit my needs.